# Restyle built-in controls without requiring BasedOn

Tags: wpf, xaml

I "re-themed" `Button` by putting a style with TargetType (but no x:key) in a ResourceDictionary and telling other developers to merge it. Now, if they want to further style the control, they need to use `BasedOn`.

Is there a way I could have themed Button without requiring consumers to used `BasedOn`?